# How to translate string to another connected string in Python

Tags: python, translate

I want to create a program that will for example if file contains word "sun" translate to "nuclear fusion", to translate word "Mars" to word "Earth" and similar.

```
import time
import os
import sys
import pyperclip
import numpy as np


translator = {
    'E' :  'L' ,
    'H' :  'O' ,
    'L' : 'S' ,
    'O' :  'A' ,
    'HELLO' : 'Salut',
}

def a():
    f_path = input("File: ")
    f = open(f_path, 'r')
    lines = f.read()
    converted_data = ""

    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        if lines[i] in translator.keys():
           converted_data += translator[lines[i]]
        else:
           converted_data += lines[i]
    print(converted_data)

a()
```

This is a part of the code, because other part doesn't have anything to do with this.When I run it, and add a file that contains word "HELLO", I get the output "OLSSA", not the word "Salut", I know that I used dict.keys() in this code and that it only uses keys, but I need it to translate whole sentences because my program isn't using one key, it's using sentences, how can I make it work with whole sentences?

Comment: `lines[i]` is an individual character.  It cannot be equal to `HELLO`.

Comment: What do you mean "program isn't using one key, it's using sentences"? Your program translates your message character-by-character because that's what you do when you iterate over the string like that and do `lines[i]`.

Comment: If you want to iterate over the file line-by-line, use `f.readlines()` instead of `f.read()`.

Comment: Unrelated: Remember that you can use `dict.get` instead of checking if the key exists. Since `dict.get` even returns a specified default when the key doesn't exist, a simple `converted_data += translator.get(lines[i], lines[i])` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your program translates your message character-by-character because that's what you do when you iterate over the string like that and do `lines[i]`.

Instead, if you wanted to translate each *word* in your  message, and fall back to translating character-by-character if the word doesn't exist, you will need to split the message into *words* instead of iterating over each character.

```
def translate_file(f_path, translator):
    translated_lines = []
    with open(f_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            t_line = []
            words = line.strip().split() # Split line into words
            # Iterate over each word
            for word in words:
                #        Try getting word from translator
                t_word = translator.get(word, 
                             translate_word(word, translator)) # Use this default if word not found in translator

                t_line.append(t_word)) 

            translated_lines.append(" ".join(t_line)) # # Join words in line by spaces, append to list of lines

    return "\n".join(translated_lines) # Join lines by \n, return result

def translate_word(word, translator):
    # Translate word character-by-character
    return "".join(translator.get(c, c) for c in word)
```

Now, if we tried calling this code with a test file:

```
HELLO WORLD 
HELO LOHE HEOL HELLO HOLE
```

```
translator = translator = {
    'E' :  'L' ,
    'H' :  'O' ,
    'L' : 'S' ,
    'O' :  'A' ,
    'HELLO' : 'Salut',
}

result = translate_file("test.txt", translator)
print(result)
# Salut WARSD
# OLSA SAOL OLAS Salut OASL
```